# replace parameter using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, jinja2

I'm working with python and jinja. When I render template I sent two parameters like this :

```
return render_template('mod_page/index.html', 
                types_first = utils.questions_first(), 
                types_second = utils.questions_second())
```

`questions_first` and `questions_second` are  two  same functions, something like this:

```
 def questions_first(self):
     return ['Name','Surname', 'Phone']
```

In index page I have a tag like this:

```
<html lang="en">
...
```

I want to take `lang` attribute with jQuery and then to check if it is `'en'` I want to use `questions_first` if it is `'sr'` I want to use `questions_second`.

My question is how can I replace the parameter `types_first` inside jinja code or put there, I don't know exactly what to do, I tried to do it like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
  var language = $('html').attr('lang');
  var selectedFunction;
  if(language == "sq"){ 
    selectedFunction = "sq";}
  else{
    selectedFunction = "sr"; }
</script>

....
    <p> Questions: </p>
    {{ _({% for type in types_first %}) }}
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="{{ type }}">{{ type }}</label>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First solution (better):**

If you want to change lang, you can use i18next framework (http://i18next.com/docs/). It's much simpler solution.

**Second solution (worse):**

Select via jQuery element you want to change -> use empty() function -> render element with changed values and assign it to selector with append()

You can also combine both solutions. Write function to rerender template and change dynamically langauge. e.g.:

```
fn_or_elt.empty();
fn_or_elt.append(markup);
fn_or_elt.i18n();
```

Comment: I already implemented changing language, as I said parameter lang can be: en or sr. So based on that I want to to change the parameter inside jinja? @hya

Comment: You could just select inputs and replace values with jQuery, but I would recommend to use Nunjucks that is port of jinja2 and it supports client-side rendering (http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/getting-started.html).